# Check: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c

I'm trying to integrate [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) in an **Autotools** project. Single tests work and run fine, however I get some issues when making use of suites as [the site explains](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_3.html#Tutorial):

```
$ make check
Making check in src
Making check in .
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
Making check in tests
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  elevator_test
gcc -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/local/Cellar/check/0.9.14/include  -g -O2   -o elevator_test elevator_test-elevator_test.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/check/0.9.14/lib -lcheck
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_elevator_create", referenced from:
      _test_elevator_create in elevator_test-elevator_test.o
      _test_elevator_is_full in elevator_test-elevator_test.o
  "_elevator_free", referenced from:
      _test_elevator_create in elevator_test-elevator_test.o
      _test_elevator_is_full in elevator_test-elevator_test.o
  "_elevator_is_full", referenced from:
      _test_elevator_is_full in elevator_test-elevator_test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [elevator_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

This is my test file: http://pastebin.com/aP341AZa.

The suite code looks exactly like the website, and running without the suite feature works like a charm. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Here's my tests `Makefile.am`:

```
TESTS = elevator_test
check_PROGRAMS = elevator_test
elevator_test_SOURCES = elevator_test.c $(top_builddir)/src/elevator/elevator.h $(top_builddir)/src/elevator/elevator_options.h
elevator_test_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@
elevator_test_LDADD = @CHECK_LIBS@
```

I'm correctly adding `CFLAGS` and `LDADD` as the site recommends, and I can see the following compilation flags when building the `test`:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/check/0.9.14/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/check/0.9.14/lib -lcheck
```

Comment: did you remember to include the library for suite, etc?

Comment: @user3629249 I edited my question to include my `Makefile.am`. It seems that it's being linked correctly: `-L/usr/local/Cellar/check/0.9.14/lib -lcheck`but maybe I'm not seeing something obvious?